# Echo join does not recieve data from broadcasted presence channel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm very basic at laravel's echo and pusher and I've been facing an issue despite the docs and tutorials. I'm trying to create a real time chat message feature in my website following a youtube video.
Excerpts of code from my controller, model, channel and app.js are below respectively:

```
public function send(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $message = $user->messages()->create([
        'user_id' => $id,
        'messages' => $request->get('messages')
    ]);
    broadcast(new MessagePosted($message, $user));
    return ['status' => 'Message Sent!'];
}
```

model:

```
 public function broadcastOn()
    {
//        return ['chatit'];
          return new PresenceChannel('chatit');
    }
```

channel:

```
Broadcast::channel('chatit', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

app:

```
window.Echo.join('chatit')
            .listen('MessagePosted', (e) => {
        console.log(e)
    });
```

My issue now is that if i return chatit (which i've commented) in my model, and change join to channel, i get to see the result of console.log, but when i use the presence channel instead, and use join in app.js, i only get message sent status.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why but after some hours of frustration, I restarted my pc and it just started working.

I also found out that terminating and rerunning php artisan serve process could also solve the issue

Comment: Upvoted for **terminating and rerunning php artisan serve**. I've wasted 1 hour trying to understand why my application does not work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my event `MessagePosted` was on a sub-directory `Chat` in `Events` directory, and to be able to log event data you must point to that sub-directory

`app\Events\Chat\MessagePosted`

```js
window.Echo.join('chatit').listen('Chat\\MessagePosted', (e) => {
   console.log(e)
})
```

and now it's working 100%